# Center a Bing map using databinding

Tags: windows-8, bing-maps, winrt-xaml

I have a ScrollViewer with a ControlTemplate that contains a Bing map, see snippet below. The Pushpin is correctly positioned so the Latitude and Longitude properties have correct values, but the map is always centered below Africa which I think it is the 0,0 position...

```
<bing:Map 
    x:Name="Karta" 
    Grid.Row="5" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Width="500" 
    Height="500" 
    ZoomLevel="5"
    Credentials="--removed--">
    <bing:Map.Center>
        <bing:Location Latitude="{Binding Latitud}" Longitude="{Binding Longitud}" />
    </bing:Map.Center>
    <bing:Map.Children>
        <bing:Pushpin x:Name="LokalPin" >
            <bing:MapLayer.Position>
                <bing:Location Latitude="{Binding Latitud}" Longitude="{Binding Longitud}" />
            </bing:MapLayer.Position>
        </bing:Pushpin>
    </bing:Map.Children>
</bing:Map>
```

Previously I did this using code (see below) but I would like to bind it instead. And I don't think I used `<bing:Map Center>` then but if I remove it from the above there is no difference.

```
MapLayer.SetPosition(LokalPin, loc);
Karta.SetView(loc, 12.0);
```

Comment: from where you take Latitude and Longitude for binding. It looks like the values are 0

Comment: Please provide your code-behind code/architecture (where Latitud is located, etc). It's probably a datacontext problem

Comment: @Fixus: As I said in the text, the Pushpin is correctly positioned which means that Latitud and Longitud have correct values. They just don't bind when used in Map.Center.

Answer (score 1):

Months too late, but maybe someone else could use this...I'm under the assumption that we want the map to update base on a backing field (Not databinding in the xaml, but a work around), and trying to centre the map using the value of the backing field...

what I do, since the databinding of a map doesn't work (happy to be corrected here)...
I set the viewmodel.propertychanged event after the intializecomponent() in the code behind file of the page containing the map.

when the viewmodel updates the coordinate properties that you want to use as the center of the map, the changed event is raised and I center the map by reading the new coordinates from the viewmodel eg:

```
    void CurrentViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                   if (e.PropertyName != "latitude") return;
                    //Karta is the name of the map
                    //assuming the properties are in double format, if not then just cast a double
                    //do something like this: 
                    var latitude = ViewModel.latitude;
                    var longitude =ViewModel.longitude;

                    Karta.Center = new Location(latitude,longitude);
                }
                Catch(Exception exception)
                {Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);}
            }
```

This is all based on assumption that your page has reference or uses a viewmodel and that the properties have a some notify property changed attached to them... If I'm off on the wrong tangent... feel free to just skip this answer...lol! Databinding the map center is a breeze using viewmodels and the viewmodel.propertychanged event in the code behind. Too easy once you have it done..

Answer (score 0):

To set a map's view in C#, use

```
Karta.SetView(loc, zoomLevel);
```

where loc is a Location object on which you want to set the centre, and zoomLevel is an integer zoom level.

You can do it in XAML as well, but it seems you mis-spelled "Latitude" (Latitud) and "Longitude" (Longitud)

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846504.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: Yes that code works, and I also included it in my post saying that this is what I was doing Before moving to data binding. But when adding the map to a ControlTemplate setting the property in C# no longer has any affect. So I need to get the data binding option to work. The missing "e" is just Swedish terms for the same,  always use Swedish when programming (including åöä in class names :-)